# $_GET works $_POST does not

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to create a create a database that stores values as soon as submit button is pressed but I got:

> "Notice: Undefined index: SUBMIT in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebSite\examp.php
>   on line 10"
>   which prevents my program from executing
>   This is my webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Dance </title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Record examination performance</h1>

<form method=post" action="examp.php">
<dl>
<dt>Man. (Email of student dancing male steps) </dt>
<dd><input type = "text" name="hemail" /></dd>
<dt>Woman. (dances female steps) </dt>
<dd><input type="text" name="shemail"/ > 
</dl>
<dt>Date of examination </dt>
<dd><input type="text" name="date" /></dd>
<dt>Style</dt>
<dd>
<select name="style" size="4">
<option value="BL">Ballroom</option>
<option value="LT">Latin American</option>
</select>
</dd>
<dt>Level</dt>
<dd>
<select name="level">
<option value="bronze">Bronze</option>
<option value="silver">Silver</option>
<option value="gold">Gold</option>
</select>
</dd>
<dt>Mark</dt>
<dd><input type="number" name="mark" />
<dd>
<p>
<button value="press " name="SUBMIT">Submit</button>
<button name="Clear" type="reset">Reset</button>
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my program:

```
<?php
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "");
if(!$connect){
    die("Failed to connect: " . mysql_error()); 
}
else if(!mysql_select_db("studentdatabase")){
    die("Failed to connect to a database" . mysql_error());
}
else{
    if($_POST['SUBMIT']){
        $man=$_POST['hemail'];
        $woman=$_POST['shemail'];
        if($man==$woman ||!$man || !$woman){
            echo "There is no parner! ";
            die("Nothing is added");
            mysql_close($connect);
        }else {
            $date=$_POST["date"];
        }
    }
}

?>
```

So it means in $_POST but when I am changing it $_GET it starts working. and the same in other variables $woman, $man etc. in other programs that I wrote it was working fine but here... Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: form method should be method="post"

Comment: And your button is missing the `type="submit"` -> `<button type="submit" value="press" name="SUBMIT">Submit</button>`

Comment: Replace your 

    `<button value="press " name="SUBMIT">Submit</button>`

to

    `<input name="SUBMIT" type="submit" value="press ">`

Comment: Thanks to all your help but it still gives me that error :(

Comment: You need to check isset($_POST['submit']) in if condition.

Comment: And <input type="submit"..   or  <button type ="submit".. , instead of button only.

Answer (score 6):

`<form method=post" action="examp.php">` should be `<form method="post" action="examp.php">`you're missing a " which means its not setting it to post.

Comment: Thanks a lot for spotting an error it still gives me that error :(

Comment: I don't think it would make a difference but try using `<input type="submit" name="SUBMIT" value="Submit">` for your button instead.

Comment: tried doesn't work :( I was just confused cause I heard that it is  better to use Post instead of GET :( Anyways thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) to catch any `$_POST` or `$_GET` inputs.
Usefull when you allow multiple entry points in your application.

Make sure you also implement an input sanitation mechanism like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [mysqli.real-escape-string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)